# Why I get segfault when initializing the struct?

Tags: c, struct, segmentation-fault, malloc

Searched around for one hour. I guess I'd better post the question here.

I simplify the code. The segfault is in the function `initMyStruct`.

```
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct {
        int * arr1;
        int * arr2;
} myStruct;

void allocMyStruct (myStruct * a, int num) {
        a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
        a->arr1 = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        a->arr2 = malloc(10*num*sizeof(int));
}
void initMyStruct (myStruct * a, int num) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)     a->arr1[i]  =  0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10*num; i++) a->arr2[i]  = -1;
}
void freeMyStruct (myStruct * a, int num) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)     free(a->arr1);
        for (i = 0; i < 10*num; i++) free(a->arr2);
        free(a);
}
int main (void) {
        int num = 3;
        myStruct * a;
        allocMyStruct (a, num);
        initMyStruct  (a, num);
        freeMyStruct  (a, num);
        return 1;
}
```

Comment: unrelated, but why is your `main` function returning 1? if a program returns 1, that's indicating a failure of some kind AFAIK. the std lib has macro's defined: `#define EXIT_SUCCESS 0` and `#define EXIT_FAILURE 1`...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because you're not keeping the pointer to the newly allocated memory, instead you use an uninitialized pointer and getting undefined behavior.

You pass the `a` variable into `allocMyStruct()`, but that call is (like all others) *by value*, so the new value being assigned to it inside the function does *not* affect the value of `a` in `main()`.

Change it so that `allocMyStruct()` either *returns* the new pointer value, or takes a pointer to the pointer. I would prefer the former, it's cleaner and using function return values often leads to better code:

```
myStruct * allocMyStruct(int num)
{
  myStruct *p;

  if((p = malloc(sizeof *p +
                 10 * sizeof *p->arr1 +
                 10 * num * sizeof *p->arr2)) != NULL)
  {
    p->arr1 = (int *) (p + 1);
    p->arr2 = p->arr1 + 10;
  }
  return p;
}
```

The above code also streamlines the memory allocation, doing it all in one big `malloc()` call which is then "sliced" into the three parts you actually need.

If the size of `arr1` is always 10 by the way, there's no point in having it dynamically allocated, it should just be `int arr1[10];` in the struct declaration.

Comment: +1 for the optimized `malloc` call I'm still awaiting my copy of _the C programming language_, so forgive my asking: is `p+1` always going to be correct, or should it be `p + sizeof *void` or something?

Comment: How do you know that `(int *)(p + 1)` is aligned for `p->arr1`?

Comment: @AlterMann: since the struct only contains `int *` in this case, there probably won't be any need for structure alignment here. But perhaps it might be worth mentioning the risks of just assuming that `p->arr1` will be at `p + 1`, the moment the struct grows, and new types are added, I suspect there could be trouble, unless the amount of bits for each member are specified explicitly... or maybe I'm just being paranoid?

Comment: @AlterMann: Damn, I've gone and commented too soon again. I completely missed and overlooked the _"is aligned for `p->arr1`"_ part of your commend. Well, I missed the word _aligned_. I believe the answer to that is: if this is what the actual struct looks like, then yes, everything should be aligned nicely. Add a short or char in there, and you're in trouble, I think. But what I'm wondering is that, since pointers are aligned differently on 64bit vs 32bit systems (4 bytes vs 8 bytes) if a simple +1 is enough... it should be, but it feels unsafe to me...

Answer (score 2):

`a` is used uninitialized, change to:

```
myStruct * allocMyStruct (int num) {
        myStruct *a;

        a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
        a->arr1 = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        a->arr2 = malloc(10*num*sizeof(int));
        return a;
}
myStruct * a = allocMyStruct(num);
```

Also, there is no need to loop in your free function

```
void freeMyStruct (myStruct * a, int num) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)     free(a->arr1);
        for (i = 0; i < 10*num; i++) free(a->arr2);
        free(a);
}
```

Must be

```
void freeMyStruct (myStruct * a) {
        free(a->arr1);
        free(a->arr2);
        free(a);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `void allocMyStruct (myStruct * a, int num)` the `a` pointer will be passed as a value and the `a` parameter is a local copy of your pointer from `main` , after you change the local `a` in any of your three functions, it will not change in `main`.

For this you have to use double pointer as a function argument, so those functions will get an address of a pointer so they can modify it.

```
#include "stdlib.h"

typedef struct {
        int * arr1;
        int * arr2;
} myStruct;

void allocMyStruct (myStruct ** a, int num) {
        *a = malloc(sizeof(myStruct));
        (*a)->arr1 = malloc(10*sizeof(int));
        (*a)->arr2 = malloc(10*num*sizeof(int));
}
void initMyStruct (myStruct ** a, int num) {
        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < 10; i++)     (*a)->arr1[i]  =  0;
        for (i = 0; i < 10*num; i++) (*a)->arr2[i]  = -1;
}
void freeMyStruct (myStruct ** a, int num) {
        free((*a)->arr1);
        free((*a)->arr2);
        free(*a);
        *a = NULL;
}
int main (void) {
        int num = 3;
        myStruct * a;
        allocMyStruct (&a, num);
        initMyStruct  (&a, num);
        freeMyStruct  (&a, num);
        return 1;
}
```

EDIT: Alter Mann is right about multiple freeing of the same address, on linux you would get instant crash for double freeing. And he has a simpler solution.